# Inequality involving a quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

Let $a,b,c$ be integers and suppose the equation
           $$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$
has an irrational root $r$ . Let $u=\dfrac{p}{q}$ be any rational no. such that $|u-r|<1$.

Prove that $$\dfrac{1}{q^2} ≤ |f(u)|≤ K|u-r|$$
for some constant $K$ . Deduce that there is a constant $M$ such that $\bigl|r\dfrac{p}{q}\bigr| ≥ M/q^2$.

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: I'm not able able to solve it!

Comment: Try to use $f(u)=f(u)-f(r)=(u-r)(a(u+r)+b)$.

Comment: @LutzL Can you please elaborate this...

Comment: Obviously, this gives an upper bound. For the lower bound, ponder on what kind of number $ap^2+bpq+cq^2$ must be. And can you check if you missed a minus sign in your last statement?

Comment: @LutzL Nope! there was nothing

Comment: Then there is an earlier error in the reproduction chain of the task. It should be $|r-\tfrac pq|\ge M/q^2$. See also  Liouville theorem (one of the many).

Comment: And the better, more strict, assumption would be that the rational number is the best approximation with denominator $q$, i.e., $|qr-p|<1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is to prove one elementary statement about [Diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation).

If $f(x)$ is an univariate polynomial of degree $d$ with integer coefficients, $r$ an irrational root and $u=\frac pq$, $p,q\in \Bbb Z$, $q>0$, with $|r-u|<1$ not itself a root, then
$$
q^df(u)
$$
is a non-zero integer, and thus 
$$
\frac1{q^d}\le|f(u)|=|f(u)-f(r)|=|u-r|\,|f'(r+\theta(u-r))|
$$
Let $K$ be a bound on the first derivative, $|f'(x)|\le K$ on the interval $x\in [r-1,r+1]$, then
$$
|u-r|\ge \frac1{K\,q^d}
$$
is a result by Liouville around 1840.

Comment: Winner of the national mathematical olympics. And $n=11$ is the only solution.